# SAS, assigning the same numbers to specific observations

Tags: loops, sas

I want to assign the same id number to every four observations. For example, if I have the following data

```
age marital gender  id
45  1   0   1
33  1   1   1
68  0   1   1
27  1   0   1
43  0   0   2
37  0   1   2
19  1   1   2
40  1   1   2
25  1   0   3
38  1   1   3
57  0   0   3
50  1   0   3
51  1   1   4
44  0   1   4
69  1   0   4
39  0   1   4
```

The last column id is something I want to produce.
Plus, the dataset have 500,000+ observations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the integer function and the built-in `_n_` variable (which increments for each observation):

```
id = int( (_n_-4)/4 )+1;
```

Comment: When I use the suggested code, first seven observations are assigned 1 and then every four observations are assigned to the same numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more compact:

```
id = ceil(_n_/4);
```